# passing value to unspecified object using delegate C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a FlowLayoutPanel containing an unspecified number of Labels, when I double click in one of them, a new Form containing a **TextBox** and a **Button** will appear, here is the code:

```
foreach (Label lb in FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    lb.MouseDoubleClick+=new MouseEventHandler(lb_MouseDoubleClick);
}

private void lb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    NewForm form = new NewForm();
    form.ShowDialog();
    ((Label)sender).Text = ...;//I want get text from TextBox of the NewForm here
}
```

I want get Text from **TextBox** of the NewForm and assign Text to the object that invoke the Form when user click the **Button** of the Form, I don't know how to use delegate to do this, please help! Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Add a public property to "NewForm" that returns the textbox' Text property.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think your best bet might be to store the TextBox value in a static variable and simply take the value from there. It'll avoid a lot of complicated work.

That said, I'm not sure of how you've implemented the NewForm class. If you've set that up to have the textbox, or the textbox's value, publicly accessible, you could set it a lot more simply.

Comment: Thank Nathan, the code above is simplified and just a part of my class which have many variables, if I put more, it will be complicated for maintaining afterwards.